# PowerShell 5.1 universe has unraveled due to unexpected output

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

I'm not sure I understand what just happened in the script below:

```
function Main {
    $testParm = 'hello world'
    function1
}
function function1 {
    $testParm | Out-Host
}
Main
```

Output

```
hello world
```

I'm evaluating `$testParm` within `Function1` which should be blank. But it's outputting `'hello world'` which was assigned only in `Main` function.

Comment: As explained in the linked answer, if you want `$testParm` to not be visible by `function1` use the `private:` scope modifier.

Comment: Wt?! That wasn’t intuitive, smh. I wouldn’t  expect that to be a default behavior.

Comment: [Unless you explicitly make the items private, the items in the parent scope are available to the child scope.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1#parent-and-child-scopes)